# SQL join table with separate ids

Tags: sql, oracle

In the case of these tables:

Table a

```
id | val 
---+-------
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | spam
```

Table b

```
id | val 
---+-------
1  | foo
2  | bar
4  | eggs
```

Table c

```
id | val 
---+-------
0  | gaa
2  | bar
3  | spam
```

How can I perform a join so the id column contains a list of all 3 tables? That is:

```
id | val 
---+-------
0  | gaa
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | spam
4  | eggs
```

Comment: You are looking for `UNION`

Comment: What if table A and table B have this same ID but different value?

Comment: will a union not lead to multiple entries? the id after col after a union turnes out to be 1,2,3,1,2,4,0,2,3. How can i prevent this with a union?

Comment: What happened to "3/spam"?

Comment: No, `UNION` will remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` would keep them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the Basic scenario, In case there is no different `val` for the same `id` use the UNION
- In case you have different `val` for the same `id` you need to use some logic to remove them as follows:

--

```
select id, val from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by num) as rn from 
(select id, val, 1 as num -- number to add logic from to give priority to the data of table
from a
union all -- duplicate do not need to be removed as we handle it using analytical function 
select id, val, 2
from b
union all
select id, val, 3
from c) t)
where rn = 1;
```

The above query will always give table `a` data for the `id`'s `val` if there is different `val` for the same id.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

How about `union`?

```
select id, val
from a
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select id, val
from b
union 
select id, val
from c;
```

This removes duplicates.

If the val might change and you want the one from the "first" table, then you can check for that:

```
select id, val
from a
union all
select id, val
from b
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id)
union all
select id, val
from c
where not exists (select 1 from a where c.id = a.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from b where c.id = b.id);
```

If there is an index on `id` (say it is a primary key), then this is likely to be faster than the first version using `union`.

Comment: @rafaelkukawski . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer